# Python Environment Tainted, should I reinstall ubuntu or python?

Tags: package-management, python, anaconda, ros

I started using python and ubuntu last year, without any prior knowledge. I started with ROS for school purposes. Without knowing anaconda and ROS has a lot of conflict working together, my python environment is not working properly. For example

```
which python
```

gives me a directory that does not exist. And a lot of the packages are not working properly due to the different versions of python it is installed in.

```
env | grep PATH; env | grep ROS
```

the command above gives me the following:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/sean/bin:/home/sean/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin    
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
PYTHONPATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_HOSTNAME=sean-Lenovo-ideapad-Y700-17ISK
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/sean/turtlebot2i/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

Should I just reinstall python or just ubuntu in general? And is there any suggestions of using python in the future? For example I have read that using apt-get instead of pip is always better.

Thanks for any response in advance.